# Oscilloscope had weird interaction with Laptop

Tags: circuit-analysis, oscilloscope, grounding

Can someone explain to me why the below situation happened? Thanks.

I tried 'debugging' a circuit. The circuit was a H bridge, and I wa using it to sent current through human body to induce feelings.

I say 'debugging' because the circuit was actually functioning correctly, however the oscilloscope was not getting the correct wave displayed, therefore I tried debugging the circuit. After some period of time, my friend came by and told me you can try unplugging your laptop's power and I did as he said. MAGICALLY! The Oscilloscope started to show the correct wave form.

We both have no idea why. I am guessing it has something to do with the grounding of the circuit.

Here is the block diagram of the circuit.
[image: Block Diagram]

EDIT. The oscilloscope is connected to the cathode and anode of the H bridge to see output.

Comment: Common problem in this forum is lack of awareness of leakage capacitance in isolation transformer causing CM noise. Ground fault will cause 0.5mA current leakage sensation. max. due to lack of earth ground. ( other than scope) Like accupuncture needle.  So to use charger, you need better Earth ground direct to circuit and very short probe ground leads or none with tip removed and across 2 pins <1cm apart. Alternative is better CM choke on charger. They use the cheapest.

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt Sorry. Which ground fault are you refering to?

Comment: I don't see an oscilloscope in that diagram anywhere or grounds

Comment: @laptop2d see edits

Comment: Be careful with grounds. The ground of an oscilloscope is typically not floating. If you connect your charger, it may be possible that it short-circuits the USB-ground to your oscilloscope's ground through the earthing pins.

Comment: @SvenB Sorry. Which earthing pins you talking about?

Comment: The earthing pins from the power outlets. The oscilloscope chassis is usually earthed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On most scopes the "ground" of the input is tied to the scopes chassis and to mains ground.

Laptops are typically floating but only at low frequencies. I just measured my lenovo power brick and got the following readings (rounded to the nearest nf as the measurements didn't seem stable beyond that.

- Mains earth <-> output 0.585uF
- Mains earth <-> input 2nF
- input <-> output 2nF

Assuming your laptops power brick is similar to mine with the latop plugged in every time your H bridge switches it has to charge about 0.5uF of capacitance.

Depending on the voltage, frequency and the current driving capacity of your H bridge this could take non-negligable time. For example if your voltage is 100V and your circuit can deliver 1A then it would take 50uS to charge the capacitance. If your H bridge is switching at 10kHz then it will take pretty much a complete half-cycle to charge/discharge this capacitance.

Unplugging the laptop's power brick substantially reduces the capacitance between the laptop and mains earth.

Comment: Thanks, this make sense, Because the scope was getting right graph when the H bridge is working at 100Hz but not at 1kHz when power connected. Thanks, alot.